# How to print PHP constants : PHP Warning: Undefined variable?

Tags: php, constants

I'm trying to get the php version in the form PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.PHP_MINOR_VERSION :

```bash
$ php -r 'print $PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.$PHP_MINOR_VERSION;'
PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $PHP_MAJOR_VERSION in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $PHP_MINOR_VERSION in Command line code on line 1
$
```

[This doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) says :

> These constants are defined by the PHP core.

How can I load them ?

Comment: constants do not use `$` - it is variables that begin with `$`

Comment: The documentation page that you refer talks about constants, Your code tries to print some variables (that are not defined). The error message should give you a hint. Read the page about [PHP constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). It says: _"A valid constant name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores."_. No starting `$`, that's for variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ php -r 'print PHP_MAJOR_VERSION . '.' . PHP_MINOR_VERSION;'
```

This will do it.

Comment: `fseydel` Your commands prints `81` instead of `8.1`

Comment: @SebMa: You're right, I edited the answer!

Comment: Now, this command returns : `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "." in Command line code on line 1`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see in your command line then php --version will show you php version.
if you want display major and minor separately you should use this example described in --
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

if you need exact code after trying this. then tell me..

Comment: you can try this - php -r 'echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.".".PHP_MINOR_VERSION;'